# Type Checking does not work with Ruby and Liquid

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I am currently making my blog with Jekyll. Jekyll custom plugin uses Ruby and Jekyll is using Liquid. I am currently getting input via custom liquid tag and processing it there. I would like to check whether the string contains integers or not. So I have the following code. I realised that the input is not of the type String but rather Jekyll::Token type. So I changed the inputs to string but I cannot detect whether string contains an integer. Here is my code:

```
module Jekyll
    class TypecheckTag < Liquid::Tag

        def is_int(word)
            return word.count("0-3000") > 0
        end 

        def initialize(tag_name, word, tokens)
            super
            @word = word.to_s

        end

        def render(context)
            if /\A\d+\z/.match(@word)
                @result = 'int'
            else
                @result = 'string'
            end
        end


    end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('typecheck', Jekyll::TypecheckTag)
```

Unfortunately, it always returns 'string' say even if we have a string "16" for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code work fine

`def render(input_str)
  if /\A[-+]?\d+\z/.match(input_str.strip)
    @result = 'int'
  else
    @result = 'string'
  end
end`

Sample input with output

```
p render('16') # "int"
p render('16a') # "string"
p render('16  ')  # "int"
p render('asd') #"string"
p render('') #"string"
```

I have used `strip` because of `render('16  ')  # "int"` If you don't want ignore that. Hope it will help you.

Comment: This is not exactly what I want but I solved it by getting the value via context.